# Error with pseudo clock in drools when I have two rules matching different events

Tags: drools

I want to test drools 6.3 with a scenario, But I have a problem in a special situation.
Here is my scenario in a simple form:
I have two systems, A and B, in a simulated Network that generate events. I want to write two rules to find out patterns in these events. Two rules for testing this scenario is:

```
declare A
  @timestamp(timestampA)
end

declare B
  @timestamp(timestampB)
end

Rule “1”
When
    accumulate( A() over window:time( 10s ) ; s:count(1) ; s>1)
Then
    System.out.println( " Rule 1 matched " );

Rule “2”
When
    B()
Then
    System.out.println( " Rule 2 matched " );
```

Timestamp of each event is the timestamp from log generated in each system on when received by drools and inserted in working memory.
I’m using STREAM mode with pseudo clock, because events from System B receives with 25min delay due to network congestion and I should adjust session clock manually. Session clock set with the timestamp of every event inserted into the session. And All rules fire when every event inserted.
When order of receiving and inserting events are like below matched correctly.

```
Event A received at 10:31:21 – Session clock : 10:31:21 – insert A and fire
Event A received at 10:31:23 - Session clock : 10:31:23 – insert A and fire
Rule 1 matched
Event B received at 10:06:41 - Session clock : 10:06:41 – insert B and fire
Rule 2 matched
```

But when order of receiving and inserting events are like below matched incorrectly:

```
Event A received at 10:31:21 – Session clock : 10:31:21 – insert A and fire
Event B received at 10:06:41 - Session clock : 10:06:41 – insert B and fire
Rule 2 matched
Event A received at 10:31:23 - Session clock : 10:31:23 – insert A and fire
```

When second A event inserted tow A events in last 10s are in working memory but rule 1 does not match. Why?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is somewhat in conflict with the assumptions underlying the CEP (Continuous Event Processing) of Drools. STREAM mode implies that events should be inserted in the order of their timestamps, irrespective of their origin. Setting the pseudo clock back and forth in big jumps is another good way to confuse the Engine.

Don't use STREAM mode, window:time and forget about session clocks.

You have facts containing time stamps, and you can easily write your rules by referring to these time stamps, either using plain old arithmetic or by applying the temporal operators (which are nothing but syntactic sugar for testing the relation of long (as in java.lang) values.

Comment: Another option (although possibly conflicting with other requirements) could be to use the pseudoclock and advance it manually accordingly to received event timestamps. I'm making reference to the Drools' twitter CBR example https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-contributed-experiments/blob/master/twittercbr/src/main/java/org/drools/examples/twittercbr/TwitterCBROffline.java#L100 for this case.
Then mitigate the delay with buffering and/or discard - this mitigation strategy could indeed be in conflicts with other requirements and therefore making this option not applicable globally.

Comment: @tarilabs But manually adjusting a pseudoclock is just what OP is doing - and it doesn't work with back-and--forth time stamps

Comment: to be precise, I was referring to Drools' pseudoclock. The (Drools') pseudoclock can only advance, if I see the log in the question looks like OP is rewinding the session's clock, hence I doubt OP is using pseudoclock, and I think OP is using a custom clock implementation breaking the contract of CEP. Using pseudoclock (which by the API can only advance) would ensure the CEP requirements are met, the problem is "deferred" then to buffering and/or discard policy to be used while advancing the pseudoclock and inserting (or discarding) events.

Comment: @tarilabs The fact that a method is called "advanceTime" doesn't mean that you can't call it with a negative value. Thus, why do you say that the pseudo clock can only be advanced?

Comment: Touché - as in these use-case scenarii I always implement a buffering and/or discard policy upstream the pseudoclock "advanceTime" method call, I think I never noticed the pseudoclock API could actually be "bent" this way. Thank you for pointing this out @laune!